# Binding issues when attempting to unwrap ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I'm starting out with WPF and trying to understand setting up MVVM correctly. Currently I have a UserControl which has a ListBox. The Listbox contains a list of Checkboxes which when checked I want to display a TabItem containing a user control associated  to that checkbox. To start I found a way to create a CheckListBox [here](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/ViewModels_and_CheckListBoxes.aspx), but now when I attempt to create the tabpage I get a binding exception related to the TabControls ItemsSource:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Items' property not found on 'object' ''DataTemplate' (HashCode=22018304)'. BindingExpression:Path=Items.CheckedItems; DataItem='DataTemplate' (HashCode=22018304); target element is 'TabControl' (Name='tc_TabItems'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'selectedItem' property not found on 'object' ''DataTemplate' (HashCode=22018304)'. BindingExpression:Path=selectedItem; DataItem='DataTemplate' (HashCode=22018304); target element is 'TabControl' (Name='tc_TabItems'); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object')
```

My MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="CheckListBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CheckListBox"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TabItemViewModel}">
        <local:TabItemUserControl />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="{x:Type local:TabItemViewModel}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding selectedItem}" Margin="4" SelectionMode="Extended" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox Name="check" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Value.Name}" Margin="1"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" >
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" >Selected Items</TextBlock>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Margin="4"  x:Name="items" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items.SelectedItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Value.Name" />
    </StackPanel>
    <TabControl Name="tc_TabItems" Grid.Column="2" TabStripPlacement="Right" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items.SelectedItems}" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding selectedItem}"
                >
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TabItemViewModel}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.DataContext>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TabItem Content="{Binding Value}"></TabItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.DataContext>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

If I remove the `TabControl.DataContext` then the binding error disappears, and the TabItems with the appropriate header appear, but obviously the DataContext is then empty.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    ...            
    public MainWindow () {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
    private TabItemViewModel _selectedItem;
    private CheckableObservableCollection<TabItemViewModel> _items;

    public CheckableObservableCollection<TabItemViewModel> Items { get { return _items; } set { SetField( ref _items, value ); } }
    public TabItemViewModel selectedItem { get { return _selectedItem; }  set {SetField(ref _selectedItem, value); }}            

    public ViewModel () {
    //Items = new CheckableObservableCollection<TabItemUserControl> { "this", "is", "a", "test" };
        Items = new CheckableObservableCollection<TabItemViewModel>();
        Items.Add( new TabItemViewModel { Name = "Name", Temp = "Temp1" } );
        Items.Add( new TabItemViewModel { Name = "Nameington", Temp = "Temp2" } );
        Items.Add( new TabItemViewModel { Name = "NameNameington", Temp = "Temp3" } );
```

*I have left out CheckableObservableCollection, and CheckWrapper as they are mostly identical to that in the link. The TabItemViewModel I felt wasn't really necessary as its a collection of properties that can be seen to be set and used in the ViewModel sample

To clarify the above errors only occur when the `TabControl.DataContext` is present (if I remove that section no errors appear in the output).

Comment: You're specifying a binding with a path of `selectedItem` and a context of type `ViewModel`. Does your `ViewModel` (which you haven't shown) have a property named `selectedItem`? If not, that explains at least that error.

Comment: @TypeIA I edited my question to show more of the ViewModel class, but yeah the ViewModel does have a selectedItem and an Items property.

Comment: "but obviously the DataContext is then empty" - why would it be empty? It should get it from it's parent, Grid. And Grid gets it from it's parent, Window. And you set the DataContext on the Window, in code, to new ViewModel().

Comment: @J.H. I think I figured it out. So I used `TabControl.DataContext` rather than `TabControl.DataTemplate`. By using the `DataContext` I'm assuming I overrode the original context which was set on the Window, which wasn't what I wanted to do.

Comment: Mike, lol... stuff like that happens to all of us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you the problem:

> 'Items' property not found on 'object' ''DataTemplate'
>   (HashCode=22018304)'

You set the TabControl.DataContext to a DataTemplate. DataTemplate does not have an Items property so you get the error.

It looks like you want the ViewModel to be the DataContext. So, just don't set the DataContext on the TabControl and it will inherit the DataContext of it's parent. It'll bubble up until it gets to the Window, which has the DataContext you set in code, new ViewModel().